# Regular expression to pick a row in an html table containing desired text

Tags: html, regex, matlab

[Sorry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but uhrm, I'd like to use regexp (actually I'd use something else but I want to do the task within a Matlab function) to pick a single row containing desired keywords within an html table.

I am using `Matlab` calling function `regexpi` (case-insensitive version of regexp), which is akin to `PHP` regex from what I can tell.

Ok, here's a snippet from such an html table to parse:

```
<tr><td><a href="blu">blu</a></td><td>value</td></tr><tr><td><a
href="bla">findme</a></td><td>value</td></tr><tr><td><a
href="ble">ble</a></td><td>value</td></tr>
```

The desired row to pick contains the word "findme".

(*added*:) Content of other cells and tags in the table could be anything (here "bla" is a dummy value)- the important part is the presence of "findme" and that a single line (not more) is caught (or all lines containing "findme" but such behaviour is not expected). Any paired name/value table in a wikipedia page is a good example.

I tinkered with https://regex101.com/ using whatever I could dig up at the Matlab documentation (forward/backward looking, combinations of :,> and ?), but have failed to identify a pattern that will pick just the right row (or all those that contain the keyword "findme"). The following pattern for instance will pick the text but not the entire row: `<tr[^>]*>[^>]*.*?(findme).*?<\/td` .

Pattern `<tr[^>]*>(.*?findme.*?)<\/tr[^>]*>` picks the row but is too greedy and picks preceding rows.

Note that the original task I had set out was to capture entire tables and then parse these, but [the Matlab regexp-powered function I found for the task](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22465-get-html-table-data-into-matlab) had trouble with nested tables (or I had trouble implementing it for the task).

The question is how to return a row containing desired keywords from an html table, programmatically, within a matlab function (without calling an external program)? Bonus question is how to solve the nested table issue, but maybe that's another question.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Are you asking for a matlab solution or a PHP solution? If it's PHP, then there are better way to parse HTML than Regex (which [isn't well suited for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2453432)). I would recommend using something like [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead. But that's if you're looking for a PHP solution. If not, please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am looking for a matlab solution (m-file or matlab function). I include PHP only because it is my understanding that matlab regexp is PHP like and thought I might find more people with PHP than matlab regexp background. Also, https://regex101.com/ which I played with does not do matlab, only PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think a PHP pattern will work equally well within Matlab.

Comment: Do you have access to the **Text Analytics Toolbox** ?

Comment: *how to return a row containing desired keywords* the keyword being "bla" ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness don't have that toolbox but thanks for the tip. The keyword example is "findme". Bla etc is just filler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you split up the string with [strsplit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and use [contains](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) for the filtering, which is a lot more readable and maintainable than a regex pattern:

```
htmlString = ['<tr><td><a href="blu">blu</a></td><td>value</td></tr><tr><td><a',...
'href="bla">findme</a></td><td>value</td></tr><tr><td><a',...
'href="ble">ble</a></td><td>value</td></tr>'];

keyword = 'findme';
splitStrings = strsplit(htmlString,'<tr>');
desiredRow = ['<tr>' splitStrings{contains(splitStrings,keyword)}]
```

The output is:

```
<tr><td><ahref="bla">findme</a></td><td>value</td></tr>
```

---

Alternatively you may also combine  [extractBetween](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extractbetween.html) and [contains](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html):

```
allRows = extractBetween(htmlString,'<tr>','</tr>');
desiredRow = ['<tr>' allRows{contains(allRows,keyword)} '</tr>']
```

---

If you must use regex:

```
regexp(htmlString,['<tr><td>[^>]+>' keyword '.*?<\/tr>'],'match')
```

Comment: Thanks, true that with strsplit this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
%<td><a href="bla">(.*?)</a>%sg
```

https://regex101.com/r/0Xq0mO/1

Comment: Sorry, should modify my question. Basically bla etc (content of other cells and tags in the table) could be anything - the important part is the presence of "findme" and that a single line is caught.